# How to determine distance from a user's location (CLLocationCoordinate2D) to a CGPath?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, cgpath

We have a few cgPaths drawn and based on a user's coordinates, we are trying to find the closest path to user.  This is how a path is drawn:

```
func createPath(){
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7915055, y: -96.8028408))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7919914, y: -96.8022031))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7910108, y: -96.8025008))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.7915926, y: -96.8016962))
}
```

I saw this function from this post for hit testing: [how-to-get-the-distance-to-a-cgpath-for-hit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463323/how-to-get-the-distance-to-a-cgpath-for-hit-testing)

```
func isPoint(point: CGPoint, withinDistance distance: CGFloat, ofPath path: CGPath) -> Bool {

    if let hitPath = CGPath( __byStroking: path,
                         transform: nil,
                         lineWidth: distance,
                         lineCap: CGLineCap.round,
                         lineJoin: CGLineJoin.miter,
                         miterLimit: 0) {
        let isWithinDistance = hitPath.contains(point)
        return isWithinDistance
    }
return false
}
```

which seems like a useful function, the the only issues is that for the parameters, you have to enter a specific distance.  What we are trying to do is to FIND the distance to the CGPath.  Is something like this even obtainable in Swift?

Comment: The `distance` variable seems to relate to the width of the line, not the distance to the line. An odd naming convention to be sure but a very thick line would yield a different result than a thin line.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this - https://andreygordeev.com/2017/03/13/uibezierpath-closest-point/